# Titanium API Textfield doubling up

Tags: titanium

I have a TextField in my app that is doubling up on the text. What I mean is if I type "dog" the it returns "dogDog" notice how it capitalized it?

```
var searchText = Ti.UI.createTextField({
      borderRadius:5,
      hintText : 'Enter Search Text',
      color:"#0000FF",
      borderColor:"#0000FF",
      font:{fontSize: 30},
      width:400,
      top:50
});
searchText.addEventListener('return',textEntered);

function textEntered(){
 Titanium.API.info(searchText.getValue());// logs "dogDog" when should be "dog"
}
```

Comment: please specify. what u want? When you enter "dog" then you want to display in log "dogDog". 'm right or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the properties which are being send with the event. (doc http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-event-return)

```
searchText.addEventListener('return',textEntered);

function textEntered(source,type,value){
    Titanium.API.info(value); // should just log 'dog'
    // var type should contain 'return'
    // var source should contain the searchText object.
}
```